# Can`t send option from Console/Kernel schedule->call to controller

Tags: laravel

I write automatic daily function and wanna send parametr to my controller function for change array value because don`t wanna write another functions like this.

This is my Kernel file.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {

        $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\Cron\CloudCronController@getCloudCT', ['1'])->daily();

    }
```

This is my Controller

```
public function getCloudCT(array $parameters = []){
        $startDate = time();
        for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++)
        {
            CloudCron::firstOrCreate([
                'start_date' => date('d-m-Y', strtotime('+'.($i-5).' day', $startDate)),
                'end_date' => date('d-m-Y', strtotime('+'.($i-4).' day', $startDate)),
                'type' => CloudCron::$type[$parameters]
            ]);
        }

    }
```

Any solution idea????
Thanks for your help)))

Comment: `->call()` is used to trigger commands, not functions. If you want to trigger a controller function I believe you need to to something like: `$controller = new Controller` and `$controller->getCloudCT([1])` in your `schedule` function

Comment: if I write `$controller = new CronCloudController (); ` it gives error when i run schedule

Comment: Allright what is the error?

Comment: `UnexpectedValueException`

```The stream or file "/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied```

Comment: it is a permission problem on you host run this command ```chmod -R 775 /var/www/insurance.unired.uz/storage/logs ``` on our server

Comment: Yes so after fixing the laravel.log issue, you will be able to see the actual error :P

Comment: okay, i will try this. thank you a lot)